# Rails: During asset precompile throws error key must be 16 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am storing my secret key in environment and /config/environments/production.rb has config.require_master_key = true uncommented

```
config.require_master_key = true
```

When running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the error

```
/Users/something/Development/wwwroot/trivial/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/something/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/something/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes
/Users/something/Development/wwwroot/trivial/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/something/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/something/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

any ideas on how to fix this error? What else can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the key you generated is longer of what rails expects https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33528#issuecomment-412677795

**Solution**

You can recreate a new one by deleting your master.key and credentials.yml.enc and run

```
rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while setting up a Rails 6.0 application on Ubuntu in production.

I was using the figaro gem for my environment variables.

The issue was that I was copying the content of the `secret_key_base` instead of the `master_key`

**Here's how I solved it**

Delete the previous `master.key` and the `credentials.yml.enc` file

Recreate a new `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc`:

```
rails credentials:edit
```

**OR**

```
EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit  # If you want to use VS Code as your editor
```

Copy the contents of the master.key, which is of this format:

```
34d3cc7c5305dde06865acfa473716cd
```

Replace my `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` value with the master_key in production:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY: "34d3cc7c5305dde06865acfa473716cd"
```

And then save it.

**Note**: You could also experience this issue if you set/specify a wrong `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in your `.env` files (`.env`, `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`). Say you just want to use it as a placeholder temporarily. This may also throw an error `key=': key must be 16 bytes (ArgumentError)` if you try to generate new `master.key` and the `credentials.yml.enc` files using `rails credentials:edit` or `EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`

What you have to do is to either provide the right `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in the `.env` file(s) or comment out the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable if you are not using it.

That's it.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Isn't `34d3cc7c5305dde06865acfa473716cd` 32 bytes?

Comment: each character is hexadecimal so 16 bits so 2 bytes, so 32 characters is 16 * 32 bits (512 bits) which is 512 / 8 bytes so 64 bytes, weird

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to ensure I remove the quotes around the key in my .env file.

It seems my server(AWS ECS Fargate) was counting the "" as part of the key. Locally it was all fine.

Before

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY="12345"
```

After

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=12345
```

Answer (score -3):

You can run this in your terminal

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key`
```

You can follow the tutorial [here](https://dev.to/raaynaldo/the-power-of-rails-master-key-36fh)